# Ansible variable not injected correctly, '[u' add by ansible

Tags: ansible

I have written a task to clone a git repo locally. It work well when repo url is hard coded but I get a `not found` when I use a variable.

Here the task

```
#roles/clone/tasks/mail.yml
---
- name: current_working_directory
  local_action: shell pwd
  register: current_working_directory

- name: check out a git repository
  local_action: git repo=https://username@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git dest="{{current_working_directory.stdout}}/roles/{{deployer_role}}/files/repo"
```

With this playbook file

```
- name:  deploy application code
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    deployer_role:
      - angular
  roles:
    - clone
    - angular
```

but when a try to define a variable in my playbook file I a `not found` due to some strange char ansible has added here the command it launch

```
/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin 'https:********@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git'\"'\"']' '/Users/jerome/Developpement/ansible/roles/[u'\"'\"'angular'\"'\"']/files/repo'
```

I have done the basic configuration

Here the task

```
#roles/clone/tasks/mail.yml
---
- name: current_working_directory
  local_action: shell pwd
  register: current_working_directory

- name: check out a git repository
  local_action: git repo=https://{{repository}} dest="{{current_working_directory.stdout}}/roles/{{deployer_role}}/files/repo"
```

With this playbook file

```
- name:  deploy application code
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    deployer_role:
      - angular
    repository:
      - username@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git
  roles:
    - clone
    - angular
```

Where does all those `[u` and`\"` come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `{{deployer_role}}` is a list this is why you have such characters, you have to loop over the potentials values you can provide to the role, so you have to do this

```
- name: check out a git repository
  local_action: git repo=https://username@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git dest="{{current_working_directory.stdout}}/roles/{{item}}/files/repo"
  with_items: "{{deployer_role}}"
```

Comment: To fix it, I haven't use with_items, I just stopped declaring my variable as list.